# Что делает вопросительный знак в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, тернарный-оператор

Что делает вопросительный знак в JavaScript? И почему его называют "тернарным оператором"?

Answer (score 3):

Это условный оператор.

```html
let result = условие 
  ? значениеЕслиУсловиеВерно
  : значениеЕслиУсловиеЛожно;
```

Подробнее тут - https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse

Answer (score 0):

Если условие перед оператором верно, то выполниться то что идёт после него, если нет, то что после двоеточия